# Timeout error on using nodemailer with cpanel custom email

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel, nodemailer

I have created a custom email in my cpanel dashboard, so I can be sending emails with my domain name. I was using google before with nodemailer it works out well, but now trying to do it with my domain host all i get is connection timeout, i don't really know where the problem is from, but my mail host is up and running.
this question may have similar duplicates but i have gone through them but no help..

my records for the host, I don't know if the TTL and record type is causing it

```
TTL: 14400
record-type : CNAME

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'mail.mydomain.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
        user: 'me@mydomain.com',
        pass: process.env.Password
        }
    });
    var mailOptions = {
        to: somebody@gmail.com,
        from: 'me@mydomain.com',
        subject: 'welcome',
        html: '<p>Hello this is a notification </p>',
    };
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, sent){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log('message sent')
        }       
    });

{ Error: Connection timeout
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/bitcoin.1/main/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:591:19)
    at SMTPConnection._onError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/bitcoin.1/main/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:564:20)
    at Timeout._connectionTimeout.setTimeout (/home/ubuntu/workspace/bitcoin.1/main/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:256:18)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', command: 'CONN' }
```

Any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: The connection is timing out, are you sure your credentials are correct and that your SMTP server is accepting connections from your application?

Comment: @ElliotBlackburn yeah i have ping the host and it is responding, imported it to my gmail account using pop3 it works i can send mails to people using it in my gmail account i wouldn't know why nodemailer console.logs out error